# how to implement google places autocomplete search box without places SDK for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm developing an android application that uses Uber like google maps place picker using kotlin. I've achieved all the required functionality but I couldn't able to find an updated tutorial on implementing place search autocomplete EditTextView.

I wanted to use google Places SDK for android to implement the earch feature, it seems the feature is depreciated and be turned off on July, 2019(as mentioned here: [Places SDK for android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro)).

It would be great if someone could help me create an EditText in android app when user types places it suggests places according to the search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the [Place Picker widget is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker), not Autocomplete. You can use [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete), either as a widget which gives you a pre-built search bar or programmatically to build a custom search UI. For the best user experience, define how you want to [constrain results](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#constrain_autocomplete_results) based location and/or types of places depending on your use case.

Sample code for a [full Autocomplete implementation](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos) is on Github, but only in Java for now.

Comment: Also, would be nice to mention.... IT COSTS MONEY with a number of requests... I'm coming from iOS and we can pull that info like the business website for FREE. Im venting lol

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to autocomplete feature by Google, one can opt for [Places Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) API that requests to search for basic fields against basic text. That will cost much less as compared to autocomplete feature. Basic fields include **formatted_address, geometry, icon,name, permanently_closed, photos, place_id,plus_code, types** that would be more than enough for someone's case.

You can compare cost [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?_ga=2.51463913.1729746263.1573503448-1185645895.1499553755).

So you can use some debounce and mechanisms to build your own search UI.